# Listview change applies after 2nd postback?

Tags: asp.net, listview, postback, lifecycle

i have a listview and a button out of this list view, on button click i want to add a "insert" row defined in InsertItemTemplate. The problem is when i click the button, this row is added(i know this because when a do any postback aftewards this row really shows), but isnt shown/rendered. So the question is: why this change doesn´t apply on the first postback - button click? here is my code:

EDIT:
Whole Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                        
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {


            ListItem ByName = new ListItem("By name", "Name");
            ListItem ByPhone = new ListItem("By phone", "Phone");
            ListItem ByEmail = new ListItem("By email", "Email");

            FilterTypeDDL.Items.Add(ByName);
            FilterTypeDDL.Items.Add(ByPhone);
            FilterTypeDDL.Items.Add(ByEmail);
            FilterTypeDDL.DataBind();
        }
    }

    //protected void ListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    //{            
        //switch (e.CommandName)
        //{
            //case "EditItem":                    
            //    break;

            //case "InsertItem":
            //    if (Page.IsValid)
            //    {
            //        string NameTxt = ((TextBox)(ListView.InsertItem.FindControl("NameTextBox"))).Text.Trim();
            //        string PhoneTxt = ((TextBox)(ListView.InsertItem.FindControl("PhoneTextBox"))).Text.Trim();
            //        string EmailTxt = ((TextBox)(ListView.InsertItem.FindControl("EmailTextBox"))).Text.Trim();
            //        DAORestaurant.InsertRestaurant(NameTxt, PhoneTxt, EmailTxt);


            //        ListView.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None;
            //        ListView.DataSource = DAORestaurant.GetRestaurants();
            //        ListView.DataBind();
            //        break;
            //    }
            //    break;

            //case "CancelCreation":
            //    ListView.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None;
            //    ListView.DataSource = DAORestaurant.GetRestaurants();
            //    ListView.DataBind();
            //    break;

            //case "Articles":
            //    Session["Restaurant"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            //    Control ArticlesCtrl = LoadControl("~/Controls/Article.ascx");
            //    ListViewItem Item = (ListViewItem)e.Item;
            //    Item.FindControl("CtrlPlaceHolder").Controls.Add(ArticlesCtrl);
        //}

    //}

    protected void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void newArticleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void NewRestaurantBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.LastItem;
        //SetDataSource();
        //ListView.DataBind();        
    }

    protected void ValidateName(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string NameTxt = ((TextBox)(ListView.InsertItem.FindControl("NameTextBox"))).Text.Trim();
        args.IsValid = (NameTxt.Length > 2 && NameTxt.Length < 51);
    }

    protected void ValidateUniqueness(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string NameTxt = ((TextBox)(ListView.InsertItem.FindControl("NameTextBox"))).Text.Trim();
        args.IsValid = DAORestaurant.IsUnique(NameTxt);
    }

    protected void ValidatePhone(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string PhoneTxt = ((TextBox)(ListView.InsertItem.FindControl("PhoneTextBox"))).Text.Trim();
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}$");
        args.IsValid = regex.IsMatch(PhoneTxt);
    }

    protected void ValidateEmail(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        string EmailTxt = ((TextBox)(ListView.InsertItem.FindControl("EmailTextBox"))).Text.Trim();
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
        args.IsValid = regex.IsMatch(EmailTxt);
    }

    protected void ShowAllBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Session["ALL"] = true;
        ListView.DataSource = DAORestaurant.GetRestaurants();
        ListView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void FilterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filterType = FilterTypeDDL.SelectedValue;
        string substring = StringTB.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
        Session["ALL"] = false;
        Session["FilterType"] = filterType;
        Session["Substring"] = substring;


        ListView.DataSource = DAORestaurant.GetRestaurants(substring, filterType);
        ListView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ListView_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        //SetDataSource();
        //ListView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ListView_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ListView_ItemCanceling(object sender, ListViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CancelMode == ListViewCancelMode.CancelingInsert)
        {
            ListView.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None;
        }
        else
        {
            ListView.EditIndex = -1;                
        }

        //SetDataSource();
        //ListView.DataBind();
    }

    private void SetDataSource()
    {
        if ((bool)Session["ALL"])
        {
            ListView.DataSource = DAORestaurant.GetRestaurants();
        }
        else
        {
            ListView.DataSource = DAORestaurant.GetRestaurants((string)Session["Substring"], (string)Session["FilterType"]);
        }            
    }
```

The code commented out is what i used before, i´ve switched to what you can see now, but the problem still persists. Only when i uncomment those 2 commented lines in each event, the changes apply instantly, but i know i cannot use such a method that many times, and it should not even be there.

Comment: full code of the code behide will be helpful

Comment: this is all i have in this btn click event, i thought setting this InsertItemPosition to .LastItem requests the operation that renders the insert row by InsertItemTemplate template.

Comment: We will need the full code behind to see how the ListView is bound and where this sits within the Page lifecycle.

Comment: What i want to reach is to bind the data once ShowAllBtn or FilterBtn is cliced. When the first one it takes all restaurants from my static class, when the second button it only finds some restaurants by the filter and display them in listview.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the order of execution. Try setting it in the `Page_Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form[NewRestaurantBtn.ClientID]))
    {
        ListView.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.LastItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: But i need to insert the insert row only when NewRestaurantBtn is clicked. This would add it into listview on each postback is that right?

Comment: @Martin, try it yourself. But as far as I know `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form[NewRestaurantBtn.ClientID])` should only be `false` if that button was clicked.

Comment: Sure i have tried it:), but this time the change appeared even on 3rd or 4th click, which confused me even more:)... i must be doing some terrible mistake somewhere